# Opengl 4.0 Texture issue

Tags: opengl, graphics, opengl-4

Hi I am trying to render texture on a rectangle. I am using GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER because I dont want texture to repeat itself.

```
glTextureParameteri(id, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTextureParameteri(id, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
```

I am expecting output to be something like this : Notice non-texels are grey which is its face color. 
[image]

But I am getting this output : 
[image]

Area mentioned in no 2 I guess can be resolved if I enable the blending but I am not getting any solution for Area 1. 
I know I havn't shared any code because I really can't ,is there any additional gl calls I need to make to resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER` clamps to the [border color defined in the texture/sampler object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_Object#Border_color). That is, texture coordinates outside the [0, 1] range will fetch that border color.

If you didn't set that border color, it will likely be black.

The clamping mode you probably want is `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`. That means that [the color you get for out-of-range fetches is the color of the nearest edge texels of the texture.](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_Object#Edge_value_sampling)